# WooCommerce customized checkout shipping info not being saved issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i write a custom website where i code the checkout-form myself.
after the payment gateway return sucess, the form submitted with different billing and shipping info, here is the form data request sent to:

```
radiobill: dif
billing_first_name: asdlkflkasf
billing_last_name: fdklsjf
billing_email: fdssdf@fdsf.com
billing_company: 
billing_address_1: klfdjsfkl
billing_address_2: 
billing_city: kdsljfskdlf
billing_country: US
billing_state: CT
billing_postcode: 90876
billing_phone: +358903249034
shipping_first_name: myship
shipping_last_name: myshiplast
shipping_email: test@mysite.com
shipping_company: 
shipping_address_1: pob 52
shipping_address_2: 
shipping_city: new york
shipping_country: US
shipping_state: NY
shipping_postcode: 21614
shipping_phone: 188844433211
shipping_method[0]: flat_rate:1
coupon_code: 
payment_method: stripe
terms: on
terms-field: 1
woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce: ecc50f9256
_wp_http_referer: /?wc-ajax=update_order_review
stripe_source: src_1HWcCqAMQd9xwn9s2lHvq4Zw
```

the order is being created, but it set the shipping and billing address the same (it takes only billing address). what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im just going by memory but there should be a field that say if billing address is != from shipping address. I guess that w/o that flag woocommerce use billing data to fill shipping data.

The field name should be "ship_to_different_address". Try to inject that flag into your post data with a value of "1" and see what happens

Comment: Good to know :)